# If Iyov 2:1 states HaYom occurs in Heaven before HaShem, does Laylah also occur in Heaven?

Tags: time, job-iyov-book-of, heaven

Understanding "Ha-Yom" in [[Iyov 2:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Job.2.1?lang=bi)] raises questions about the occurrences of Yom and possibly Layla in Heaven.

> Now [The-Day] came about that the divine beings presented themselves before YHVH. The-Adversary came along with them to present himself before YHVH ( וַיְהִ֣י הַיּ֔וֹם וַיָּבֹ֙אוּ֙ בְּנֵ֣י הָֽאֱלֹהִ֔ים לְהִתְיַצֵּ֖ב עַל־יְהֹוָ֑ה וַיָּבֹ֚א גַם־הַשָּׂטָן֙ בְּתֹכָ֔ם לְהִתְיַצֵּ֖ב עַל־יְהֹוָֽה )

**If הַיּ֔וֹם "Ha-Yom" in Iyov 2:1 proves Day occurs in Heaven before HaShem as Day occurs on הָ-אָֽרֶץ HaArets, does לָיְלָה "Laylah" also occur in Heaven?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [Masechta Chagigah 12b](https://www.sefaria.org/Chagigah.12b.7?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&lang=bi) it writes:

> מָעוֹן שֶׁבּוֹ **כִּיתּוֹת שֶׁל מַלְאֲכֵי הַשָּׁרֵת שֶׁאוֹמְרוֹת שִׁירָה בַּלַּיְלָה** וְחָשׁוֹת בַּיּוֹם מִפְּנֵי כְבוֹדָן שֶׁל יִשְׂרָאֵל שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר יוֹמָם יְצַוֶּה ה׳ חַסְדּוֹ **וּבַלַּיְלָה שִׁירֹה עִמִּי**
>
> Ma’on, habitation, is where **there are groups of ministering angels who recite song at night** and are silent during the day out of respect for Israel, in order not to compete with their songs, as it is stated: “By day the Lord will command His kindness, **and in the night His song is with me**” ([Psalms 42:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.42.9?lang=bi)), indicating that the song of the angels is with God only at night. (Sefaria translation and notation - my emphasis)

Another reference to 'night' in the Divine realm which also picks up on the pasuk listed in Tehillim above is mentioned in [Avoda Zarah 3b](https://www.sefaria.org/Avodah_Zarah.3b.13?lang=bi) where it writes:

> ובליליא מאי עביד איבעית אימא מעין יממא ואיבעית אימא רוכב על כרוב קל שלו ושט בשמונה עשר אלף עולמות שנאמר (תהלים סח, יח) רכב אלהים רבותים אלפי שנאן אל תקרי שנאן אלא שאינן ואיבעית אימא יושב ושומע שירה מפי חיות שנאמר (תהלים מב, ט) יומם יצוה ה' חסדו ובלילה שירו עמי
>
> The Gemara asks: And during the twelve hours of the night, what does God do? The Gemara answers: If you wish, say that the night is similar to the day, i.e., God performs the same activities as in the day. And if you wish, say instead that He rides on his light cherub and flies in eighteen thousand worlds, as it is stated: “The chariots of God are twenty thousand, even [shinan] thousands” ([Psalms 68:18](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.68.18?lang=bi)). Do not read it as even [shinan], rather read it as: That which are not [she’einan]. Since the minimum of thousands is two thousand, the phrase: That which are not thousands, indicates that two thousand are not present, i.e., the chariots of God are twenty thousand minus two thousand, which means that God rides in eighteen thousand worlds. And if you wish, say instead that God sits and listens to the songs from the mouths of the angelic creatures, as it is stated: “By day the Lord will command His loving-kindness, and in the night His song shall be with me” (Psalms 42:9). (Sefaria translation and notation)